# mysql_error() not displaying an error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to debug my code but mysql_error() isn't displaying anything. I know there is something wrong, because when I write

```
or die("ERROR");
```

It displays ERROR. So the problem must be with that line of code. When I write

```
or die(mysql_error());
```

It shows up blank. Here is my code for the line that I think has the error:

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql6) or die(mysql_error())) {
```

Now here is the full code block:

```
$sql6 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM replies WHERE thread_id = $thread_id");
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql6);
    $replies = '';
    if ($numRows < 1) {
        $replies =  "There are no replies yet, you can make the first!";
    } else {
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql6) or die(mysql_error())) {
            $reply_content = $rows['5'];
            $reply_username = $rows['7'];
            $reply_date = $rows['8'];
            $reply_author_id = $rows['4'];

            $sql9 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$reply_author_id'");
            $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql9); 
            if ($numRows < 1) {
                while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql9)) {
                    $reply_user_fn = $rows['first_name'];
                    $reply_user_ln = $rows['last_name'];
                    $reply_user_id = $rows['id'];
                    $reply_user_pp = $rows['profile_pic'];
                    $reply_user_lvl = $rows['user_level'];
                    $reply_user_threads = $rows['threads'];
                    $reply_user_email = $rows['email'];

                    $replies .= '<tr><td valign="top" style="border: 1px solid black;">';
                    $replies .= '<div class="reply" style="min-height: 125px;"';
                    $replies .= '<h2>Re: ' . $thread_title . '</h2><br />';
                    $replies .= '<em>by: ' . $reply_username . ' - ' . $reply_date . '</em><hr />';
                    $replies .= $reply_content;
                    $replies .= '</div></td>';
                    $replies .= '<td valign="top" width="200" align="center" style="border: 1px solid black;"';
                    $replies .= '<img src="userdata/profile_pics/' . $reply_user_pp . '" width="80" height="80"><br />';
                    $replies .= '<a href="profile.php?u=' .$reply_username . '" style="color: black;">'. $reply_username .'</a><br />';
                    $replies .= '<a href="profile.php?u=' .$reply_username . '" style="color: black;">' . $reply_user_fn.' ' .$reply_user_ln . '</a><br />';
                    $replies .= 'Threads: ' . $reply_user_threads . ' <br />Level: '. $reply_user_lvl .'<br />Sign up date: ' . $reply_user_email/*PUT SIGNUP DATE*/ .'';
                    $replies .= '<input type="button" name="addfriend" value="Add Friend">';
                    $replies .= '</td>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong and why won't PHP display the mysql error?
Thanks

Comment: You put `or die(mysql_error())` after `mysql_query`, not `myqsl_fetch_array`, and then you upgrade to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: First (or should I say 2nd) change this `WHERE thread_id = $thread_id"` to `WHERE thread_id = '$thread_id'"` which is most likely the `why`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That didn't do anything

Comment: Well, you have problems elsewhere then. I'll see if I can't find anything else. But that's one of the issues.

Answer (score 5):

Do not put `or die()` inside of a loop condition. The loop condition becoming `false` is what signals the loop to end, and that will also trigger `die()` *every time your loop completes*.

`mysql_fetch_row()` returns false when there are no more rows this is what is triggering your `die()` statement despite there being no error.

Comment: This is the correct answer.   PHP will continue evaluating anything in the loop condition, AFTER an "or" ... if the part BEFORE the "or" is true.   It simply wants to know if the whole condition is true. Die is a function so it will be called and your code will..die.  But your mysql_error will return an empty string, because there is no error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `try..catch` block to understand why your code is not working correctly, like this:

```
try {
  while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql6)) {
    // your code ..
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  echo "---";
  echo mysql_error();
}
```

**Note that**, as you say `or die` is getting executed, which means that there is an error in your code somewhere, and not a `mysql error`. And, therefore, the above code will capture that exception and display it for you. Also, it will display any `mysql_error`, if it has occurred until that point for reference, so that you can compare the two strings.

Comment: do you check error reporting on php.ini. If error_reporting is on then above code should work.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions do not throw exceptions. ever.

Comment: @Sammitch: I know... But, in this particular case, the user is stating the `or die` is getting executed, and therefore, there must be an error and not a `mysql_error()`, which is what is being captured for the user by this code. Updated my answer to reflect this view.

Comment: There is not error. At least not in this block of code. @user3112869 putting `or die()` in the loop condition will *always* trigger the `die()` when the loop ends regardless of if an error happened or not. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20694937/1064767).

Comment: @Sammitch: thank you for enlightening me.. upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `mysql_error()` because `mysql_query()` is probably correct.

You do `mysql_error()` **immediately after** the query, because it will show a message if the **query** was wrong, not the PHP code that gets the rows.

```
$conn = mysql_connect(....);
$sql6 = mysql_query("...", $conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));
// ...
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array()) { ... } // There's no mysql_error() here, it will return a data set (or not enter the while code block if it's null9
```

Comment: I am not getting any errors at on the queries. So what is the problem with my code?

Comment: But there is an error... `because when I write or die("ERROR"); It displays ERROR.`

Comment: Look at the edit, I added the `$conn` variable. Does it work that way? http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-error.php

Answer (score 0):

If still no mysql error, after changing the "or die" position after "mysql_query"..do you get $thread_id from somewhere?? like

```
$thread_id=$_GET['thread_id'];
```

Also, if you use, multiple database connections, inside mysql_error('$connection_name'))

Like:

```
//Connect to database
$main = mysql_connect(DB_HST, DB_USR, DB_PSS);
mysql_select_db(DB_DB);

$main2 = mysql_connect(DB_HST2, DB_USR2, DB_PSS2);
mysql_select_db(DB_DB2);
```

return the error executing the query to the right database..

```
mysql_query("query") or die (mysql_error($main));
```

when using multiple database connection the query should look like:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=1", $connection_name);
mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Comment: I am using "$result = $mysqli->query($sql); " and it returns false. Then I do "echo $mysqli->error();" and nothing is displayed. For some reason, mysqli->error() returns nothing even when an error occurs. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem of not seeing any error messages from mysql. After research it appeared that the problem has got nothing to do with PHP itself, but with mysql server configuration. The default value of the variable **lc_messages_dir** pointed to non existing directory. After adding a line in mysqld.cnf, then restarted the mysql server, and finally it worked. For me the following was the right one:

```
lc_messages_dir=/usr/share/mysql
```

It is described in mysql reference manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-message-language.html